# Как в SQL Oracle добавить в таблицу вычисляемый столбец?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица с данными, есть формула, по которой рассчитано значения последнего столбца. Как мне создать ещё один столбец, заполнить его значениями, вычисленными по формуле  для дальнейшего сравнения двух столбцов этой таблицы ? Например, есть таблица из трёх столбцов: В первом единицы, во втором двойки, а в третьем их сумма. Я хочу создать ещё один столбец (4-й), который я заполню формулой суммирования 1-го и второго столбцов, чтобы в результате весть столбец имел значение "3", как и 3-й столбец.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цель: В рамках тестирования проверить правильно ли реализовано заполнение таблицы (3-й столбец) по конкретной формуле. Я хочу добавить свой столбец с логикой, прописанной в спецификации по расчёту этого столбца и сравнить есть ли строки с отличающимися значениями 3 и 4 столбцов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если для вычисления требуется несложная формула, использующая только колонки таблицы и  встроенные функции, то для этих целей подойдет виртуальный столбец:

```
alter table <ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ> add COLUMN4 as (COLUMN1 + COLUMN2);
```

Для более сложных вычислений необходимо использовать триггер, срабатывающий при изменении данных строки:

```
create or replace trigger TRG_BER_VERIFY
  before insert or update
  on <ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ>
  for each row   // для каждой строки
begin
  :new.COLUMN4 := :new.COLUMN1 + :new.COLUMN2;
end TRG_BER_VERIFY;
```

Comment: А как это сделать не изменяя таблицу ? Т.е. есть таблица, я в запросе создал дополнительно расчетное поле, рассчитал, сравнил результаты и запрос в итоге вернул строки, которые не совпали. При этом первоначальная таблица осталась неизменной

Comment: Тогда это еще проще: написть функцию с необходимыми параметрами и использовать или в запросе, или представалении.

`create or replace function CheckSum(in_val1 integer, in_val2 integer) return integer ...`

Answer (score 0):

Вам так же можно строить непосредственно в любом запросе дополнительный расчетный столбец, сразу в SELECT

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d46b2d/7/0

```
create table test_sum as (select 1 value1, 2 value2, 3 sum from dual
                     union
                      select 2 value1, 3 value2, 4 sum from dual
                     union
                      select 5 value1, 6 value2, 7 sum from dual
                     union
                      select 8 value1, 9 value2, 10 sum from dual
                     union
                      select 11 value1, 12 value2, 13 sum from dual) 




       select value1, value2, sum, value1+value2 PROVERKA from test_sum
```